# Java Collections: Interfaces and Abstract classes

Tags: java, collections

All Collections implements interface [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), these collection have specific abstract hierarchy e.g.

- [AbstractCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) -> [AbstractList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) -> [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- [AbstractCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html) -> [AbstractSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html) -> [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

But there are also corresponding interfaces like [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). These interface seem to me kind of redundant.

Why are they here ? Is is just convention or is there a reason to just implement interface and not extend the abstract class.

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html first

Comment: There is already a part of the answer in the javadoc. An interface is a contract with no implementation while an abstract class is a contract with some implementation. It will depends on your needs, you might want rely on the existing implementation (abstract) or you may find this latter not adequate for your project (interface).

Comment: It just seemed to me, that these interface does not have another use outside collection and that these abstract skeleton classes is everything that is needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The interfaces are there because it's good to be able to assign a type to a variable or parameter without imposing an implementation.

For instance if I create a persistent entity to use in Hibernate, and it has a collection of things, I want to assign a type of List or Set to that. Hibernate will swap out whatever list I initialize it to with its own, with some Hibernate-specific implementation that does lazy-loading or whatever else it needs to. The Hibernate developers may not want to be constrained by having to extend the abstract class.

The abstract class exists as a convenience for implementers. The interface is a contract used by clients.

Comment: This. This is very sound advice.

Comment: So if they did use Abstract class and extended it, they would be constrained by its implementation, because interface is more lightweight. Am I getting it right ?

Comment: @Jellyfication: yes, the interface doesn't impose any particular implementation. Most of the time if you have a Map or a Set or a List, you want to be able to write code that doesn't care about the implementation (I don't mean the implementation doesn't matter, just that you want to separate the concerns).

Comment: @Jellyfication: The tradeoff is what happens when you edit an Abstract class long after it's been inherited multiple times (down the road) vs editing an Interface when it's been implemented by multiple classes.

Adding features to abstract classes are imediatelly visible thruout the class hierarchy, adding to interfaces requires manually updating every implementor of the said interface WITH the required functionality.

Comment: I know. Could you give me specific scenario in which somebody would be limited if he used AbstractList insted of List. What wouldn't he be able to do ?

Comment: Ok I probably get it now. I probably figured that AbstracList is so lightweight (has a little implementation or nobody would be constrained with that implementation) that it can substitute Interface itself. Or something in that manner.

Comment: @Jellification: there is still some implementation in the abstract class. one of the problems you have when you have to come up with an API is you can't forsee what people are going to do, and you don't want to lock them out of doing it needlessly (esp. since your future self is likely to be one of those unpredictable people). so the interface is there to provide a minimal contract that lays out the expected behavior with no restriction on implementation. since their decisions can't be backed out easily or at all, that makes API writers very cautious.

Comment: So in this Collection example, interfaces are kind of a backup plan. Implementation in abstract classes is probably not gonna changed, but they are safe, because they are supported by interfaces that dont really on implementation. Am I getting closer or farther away ?

Comment: @Jellification: interfaces are the absolute minimum that the api designer wants to commit to in order to provide something useful for the client. abstract classes provide common functionality that implementors may find useful, but are not forced to use.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing an interface is much different from extending an abstract class.

Let's suppose that class Animal is an abstract class, and that Dog, Cat, Snake and Shark extend Animal.

The default Animal.move() implementation simply moves them.

But, interfaces allow us to further group-out similar animals, such as RunningAnimal, SwimmingAnimal.

So, if Dog extends Animal implements RunningAnimal, along the inherited move() he will also have to implement his own run(), which might find it's way in the overridden move() inherited from Animal. Does this make sense to you yet or do I need to clarify better / with some code? :)

Interfaces let you group similar functionality of different classes. "Clickable", "Sortable", "Serializable" ... They all encompass the members thru a shared functionality (so a list of clickables is more than a list of buttons) rather than a same purpose.

So, think about it like this

```
Cat extends Animal implements RunningAnimal, ClimbingAnimal  -- inherits move() has to implement run() and climbTree()
Dog extends Animal implements RunningAnimal  -- inherits move(), has to implement run()
Snake extends Animal                         -- likely overrides inherited move()
Shark extends Animal implements SwimmingAnimal -- likely overrides move(), has to implement swim()
```

Comment: It just seemed to me, that these interface does not have another use outside collection and that these abstract skeleton classes is everything that is needed.

Comment: Sometimes interfaces are also used to work out the problem before the actual implementation arrives. When you work in teams, it's useful to agree on interfaces on monday so that on friday you have zero problems integrating your code since you knew how it was supposed to interract from the beginning :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not ? Abstract classes are made to simplify inheritance process. When you want to create your collection you don't have to do everything from scratch.

But of course no one tells you that you SHOULD inherit from AbstractCollection. You can write your implementation from scratch.

This is a common good practice for API's to have interfaces. And have distinction between implementations and interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

An Interface is a contract made between users and implementers. An abstract base class is intended to be used as a common base to access a number of similarly-behaving objects.

Comment: So abstract class could be used insted, but is more conveniet to use Interface, since it does not bear any implementation. Kind like a convention. Something like that ?

Comment: It's not a convention, it's a case-by-case thing. Sometimes you want an interface, sometimes you want a commonly-shared implementation that you want to further flesh out.